# Node.js Error - AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: pattern should not use global or sticky mode ... after reinstalling packages

Tags: node.js

I have two node.js projects running on v10.14.2. Both were working fine.

Then I deleted all packages in the package.json and reinstalled them like this:

```
$ npm install <package01> <package02> <package03> ...
```

Installation was successful. 
added 228 packages from 155 contributors and audited 393 packages in 11.48s found 0 vulnerabilities

When trying to run it I now get a Error message though:

```
$ nodemon project01
```

Error Message:

```
[nodemon] starting `node project01.js`
/home/Project01/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:553
    throw new Assert.AssertionError({
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: pattern should not use global or sticky mode
    at new AssertionError (internal/assert.js:269:11)
    at Object.exports.assert (/home/Project01/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:553:11)
    at internals.String.regex (/home/Project01/node_modules/joi/lib/types/string/index.js:122:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Project01/helpers/routeHelpers.js:58:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The same for the second app:

```
$ npm install <package01> <package02> <package03> ...
```

Installation was successful. 
added 151 packages from 116 contributors and audited 303 packages in 10.571s found 0 vulnerabilities

```
$ nodemon project02
```

Error Message:

```
[nodemon] starting `node project02.js`
/home/Project02/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:553
    throw new Assert.AssertionError({
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: pattern should not use global or sticky mode
    at new AssertionError (internal/assert.js:269:11)
    at Object.exports.assert (/home/Project02/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:553:11)
    at internals.String.regex (/home/Project02/node_modules/joi/lib/types/string/index.js:122:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Project02/helpers/routeHelpers.js:47:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What am I missing and what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You need to validate package versions you were using in package.json as just doing npm install <package-name> will install latest stable version of a package.

Comment: I wanted to install all the latest version to be up to date from a security perspective ... but is this not a good strategy/habit to do in regards to compatibility?

Comment: It is but you need to check diff of these packages as major changes in version can hamper your old implementation (due to changes in new methods/features), would recommend to go through the changes in the new versions and also update your code accordingly.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is from **@hapi/joi** when you upgraded to *v14*. There is a breaking change with regular expressions for `object.pattern` and `string.regex`. You can no longer use global (g) or sticky (y) flags. These flags were previously ignored, but now they are rejected.

For example the global was ignored
`joi.string().regex(/^[a-z0-9_-]{1,25}$/ig)`

Now the global flag must be removed
`joi.string().regex(/^[a-z0-9_-]{1,25}$/i)`

Reference the **@hapi/joi** release notes
https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1615